# Why isn't PlayerPrefs.GetInt() in unity not working?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a project where I want to make a Scoreboard scene but before I started, I wanted to know and understand what `PlayerPrefs.GetInt()` was. After reading the api, I did a test to see if it works. I went to the registry editor on windows, went to my project and added a new string value called Player Name, and I attached an `int` value of 20, just for the test. I created an `int` variable called `number` and I made it `public` so I can see what value is attached to it when I ran unity. Here is my script:

```
public int number;

void Start() {
    number = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("Player Name", 10);
}
```

And for some kind of reason, the only number attached to `number` is 10. Why? I would really appreciate your help. If you have any questions, you can simply ask.

Comment: we'd probably need more code than that to offer an answer

Comment: What did you edit/add to the registry?

Comment: All of the code I did was that and all I needed to know was how does PlayerPrefs really work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I went to the registry editor on windows, went to my project and added
>   a new string value called Player Name

That's just wrong. You don't set PlayerPrefs from the Registry. You use the `PlayerPrefs.SetInt` to save it and `PlayerPrefs.GetInt` to read it.

Save:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Player Name", 20);
PlayerPrefs.Save();
```

Read:

```
int number = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Player Name", 20);
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time. I really appreciate your help.